# Queue a build from branch B with shelveset from trunk A

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, branch, branching-and-merging, shelveset

I'm trying to get a tfs build with a specific shelveset.
I need a build of branch A and the shelveset from Branch B.
When I right click the build definition of branch A and select 'Queue Build' I can choose 'latest source with shelveset' and selecting the shelve from branch B but I get an error "Exception Message: TF400921: No shelvesets could be unshelved for this build. The build will not proceed"

If I will queue a build from branch B with the shelveset if will work.

How can I ran a build from one branch with shelveset of another branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant unshelve code to a branch other than the one it came from. The TFS Power Tools provide a way to do this.

tfpt.exe unshelve

You will need to download and install the power tools and then unshelve the code to the branch that you want. If you then shelve from the correct branch your build process will work.